# What is the correct header/payload for this voucher site in python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm setting up a python script, that checks if voucher codes are still valid.
(Site is: "https://www.lieferando.de/checkVoucher.php")

I works in Postman and ARC but I can't get it to work with Python Requests. I also tried the create code function from Postman but its still not working.

```
url = "https://www.lieferando.de/checkVoucher.php"

payload = {'vouchercode': "TRF5RCF6VRLZ7552"}
headers = {
    'vouchercode': "TRF5RCF6VRLZ7552",
    'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'User-Agent': "PostmanRuntime/7.11.0",
    'Accept': "*/*",
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "143f10f9-4bfc-4bfe-9cb9-ae4159118c7c,14eebeb3-f79b-4dea-9279-328e5dad1850",
    'Host': "www.lieferando.de",
    'cookie': "visid_incap_1716123=fad1eRraQbSyEro92B7ouuB0y1wAAAAAQUIPAAAAAAAhvXPqviZx2wjoycs1g4Fc; incap_ses_727_1716123=+tNFCxebHDoMdSkWn9MWCljCy1wAAAAAzwDNwJi0+rHL/bgMW1zj3Q==; incap_ses_184_1716123=geD7AxnPrHLB4TighrSNAnuFy1wAAAAAFTCb2kBj03wyR2BVXlobyg==; incap_ses_876_1716123=tlZZBSxfnSPJPB4gFi4oDI6Ly1wAAAAAWxnq9RAJRBvFTuNF7EhDEw==; incap_ses_730_1716123=JW8oXiBsrk8SYz8T/3shCmCRy1wAAAAApG2tibhMTuqnZBYjb+JDGg==; incap_ses_536_1716123=GY3ddNoWphYa0bcoG0JwB+mXy1wAAAAAxqvjmrYrd4ZqhbHGH418eQ==; nlbi_1716123=4oBPV9c8liHrbOgrX9BzAQAAAADFGnUou8G0vVD66E07GFpV; incap_ses_246_1716123=Oka1Xjj8WAEkqd1TwPdpA/qly1wAAAAAWjqXqiPrP3pj1mpDS572Lg==; incap_ses_108_1716123=madBJ0JEly173VQl8LN/Ab+1y1wAAAAAzTICVw2c/Vk5RibweBnRHQ==; incap_ses_877_1716123=atGOOty1yBkTqVcPrLsrDG+KzFwAAAAAtCkMsl02gWsI0TCmJVWhjQ==; PHPSESSID=j812qmhlang0kvh8rfdulhkm56",
    'accept-encoding': "gzip, deflate",
    'content-length': "1376",
    'Connection': "keep-alive",
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Server should response with

```
{"basketResponse":null,"status":"error","value":"Alle Gutscheine mit diesem Gutscheincode wurden bereits verwendet. Es sind keine Gutscheine verf\u00fcgbar und somit ist der Code nicht mehr g\u00fcltig."
```

But responds with

```
{"basketResponse":null,"status":"error","value":"Bitte gib den Gutscheincode ein","markfields":["ivouchercode"]}
```

Comment: I tested it in Postman and didn't get the desired response either.

Comment: well it seems the API is expecting `ivouchercode` but you're sending `vouchercode`?

Comment: I tried ivouchercode aswell didn't work postman works with following headers:
vouchercode:TRF5RCF6VRLZ7552
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
body (raw):
{"vouchercode": "TRF5RCF6VRLZ7552"}

Comment: Translate the German please.

Comment: "Alle Gutscheine mit diesem Gutscheincode wurden bereits verwendet. Es sind keine Gutscheine verf\u00fcgbar und somit ist der Code nicht mehr g\u00fcltig. "
means "All codes of this voucher have been used and the code is not valid anymore."


"Bitte gib den Gutscheincode ein" means
"Please enter a Vouchercode"

Comment: I made progress by adding a PHPSESSID cookie helped me make it run in python. Now I need to make sure it works everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a couple of problems with your code:

1. You should send `payload` as a JSON string (so replacing `data=` with `json=`)
2. The `headers` that you are using aren't correct
3. You should include cookies in your POST request (you can do it automatically using `requests.session()`)

All in all your code should look something like this:

```
import requests

session = requests.session()

url = "https://www.lieferando.de/checkVoucher.php"

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0", "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", "DNT": "1", "Connection": "close", "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1"}
session.request("GET", "https://www.lieferando.de/bestellung-abschliessen-miran-pizza-doener", headers=headers)

payload = {'vouchercode': "TRF5RCF6VRLZ7552"}
response = session.request("POST", url, json=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.json())
```

*(PS:
`response.json()` converts `response` into a JSON string, which makes it easier to work with. If not needed you can use `.text` instead)*

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I think that did the trick :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped feel free to tell me if you run into the issues!